# How to add an entry to 'Authorized redirect URIs' via Google API?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to add a new entry to 'Authorized redirect URIs' list but I can't seem to be able to find an API that would allow me to do that.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

[image]